Removing the control panel during model windowAnylogic
I know this is possible, but I could not find the solution anywhere on stackoverflow or on the anylogic guide.
But my problem is that I want to delete the control panel, when running my simulation model as stand alone application, so that you do not see the bar at the bottom as shown below:

I think it is in some kind of coding at the start up of main like:
getExperimentHost().setRunControlEnabled(false);
But than to disable the presentation

Afaik, you cannot remove the control bar (except by manually switching to full screen).
All controls and what you can do are in the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/ipresentation.html

Hi Benjamin, Thanks for the help. I'm almost 80% sure I saw someone do it once, perhaps it was by changing the java code in notepad or something, but not sure. So perhaps you are right!
